# Play songs in the file system queue only once?

Tags: banshee, music

In the "file system queue", once all the songs are done, playback returns to the "play queue", that is exactly what I want. The problem is, when I add a new song to the "file system queue", once *that* song is finished, it proceeds to play another song from the "file system queue" and *then* proceed to the "play queue". So far, the only pattern I've found is that the next song played song is always the next one alphabetically.

Is there anyway to automatically remove songs from the "file system queue" once they are done playing, or for each queued song to play only once?

Edit: The pattern doesn't some to be alphabetically, but rather random.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this (currently). Your best bet is to report a bug on Banshee's bug tracker, requesting that the behavior be changed.

The only other option is to select "Stop when finished" from the Playback menu and then manually chose another track after the song finishes.